# Outlook messages read from a Windows folder are blank for certain values

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Given a directory containing several thousands Outlook MSG files, I want to use Excel to read certain pieces of the message metadata and map it to a worksheet. However, VBA returns certain fields as blank, such as Sender.

I expect one attachment per email. I'm trying:

```
Sub SaveOlAttachments()

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
Dim fpath As String
Dim outPath As String
Dim writeRow As Long

fpath="some\path"
outPath="some\path"
writeRow = 2

strFile = Dir(fpath & "\" & "*.msg")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Set Msg = objOL.Session.OpenSharedItem(fpath & "\" & strFile)
    If Msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
         For Each att In Msg.Attachments
             att.SaveAsFile outPath & "\" & att.Filename
             Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = Msg.Subject
             Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = att.Filename
             Cells(writeRow, 3).Value = Msg.SentOn
         Next
    End If
    writeRow = writeRow + 1
    strFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

However, when looking at Msg in my Locals window, I get blank values for SenderEmailAddress, BCC, Body, Recipients.

I know this is wrong immediately upon opening any one of the emails.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the problematic  MSG files with OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy - click OpenIMshOnOStg button)?

Comment: `writeRow` is only incremented after each Msg, not after each attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that copying the files from my network drive into a folder in my Outlook inbox brought the values back to where I could see them again in Outlook.

Instead of making a workbook in Excel, I used the below method in Outlook's VBE to map the data I needed from each email into a csv that I could then save.

```
Sub read_drta()

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.folders("my_email@address.com")
Set objFolder = objFolder.folders("Inbox")
Set objFolder = objFolder.folders("imports")
fpath = "C:\Users\Email_Tasker"

my_csv = fpath & "\data.csv"

Open my_csv For Output As #1

For Each Item In objFolder.Items

    myLine = Item.Subject & "," & Item.SentOn & "," & Item.SenderEmailAddress & "," & Item.Attachments(1).FileName
    Print #1, myLine
Next Item

Close #1
End Sub
```

The "Item" object contained everything in Outlook VBA, but oddly it still kept the same fields empty in Excel.